# Associate existing shared steps with a test case programmatically

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to add a shared step to a test case that is being created using

```
CreateWorkItemAsync()
```

It is no problem to create test steps and add them to the test case

```
ITestStep testStep1 = testBase.CreateTestStep();
```

but I am trying to add an existing shared step to the test case. I cannot find a way in the Azure Devops SDK to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is creating the test case using

```
 CreateWorkItemAsync()
```

and then getting that work item using

```
GetWorkItemAsync()
```

and then editing the field

> Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps

as xml and inserting my own nodes into the proper places to add shared steps to the test case. You can see the format of the shared steps by getting a test case with an API GET request and looking at the format of Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [ISharedStepReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/dd780488(v%3Dvs.120)) Interface which used to call a shared step set from a test case.

You should be able to add a shared step into a specific test case. A code snippet for your reference:

```
ITestManagementService testService = tfsCollection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
ITestManagementTeamProject teamProject = testService.GetTeamProject(teamProjectName);

//find test case by testcase id
ITestCase testcase1 = teamProject.TestCases.Find(192); //192 is the testcase id

//find share steps by sharedstep id
ISharedStep sharedStep1 = teamProject.SharedSteps.Find(140); //140 is the shared step id

//Add shareSteps to the specific test case
ISharedStepReference sharedStepReference = testcase1.CreateSharedStepReference();
sharedStepReference.SharedStepId = sharedStep1.Id;
testcase1.Actions.Add(sharedStepReference);
testcase1.Save();
```

Comment: But using teamProjoect.SharedSteps.Find() is getting a reference to a shared step on TFS. I am trying to add a reference to a shared step on Azure to a Test Case on Azure.

Comment: @John Are you talking about Azure DevOps the online version which url kind like `https://dev.azure.com/xxx`

Comment: yes that's what's being used. The overall goal is moving TFS items to dev.azure, which is straightforward so far except for associating shared steps.

Comment: Hi John, then you could try to use JS Client. (vss-sdk-extension) Take a look at this blog: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/how-to-use-test-step-using-rest-client-helper/ It describe through these clients you can create test artifacts such as test cases with test steps, test step attachments, shared steps, parameters, shared parameter. You can find comprehensive samples for both C# and JS here on GitHub project: [RESTApi-Sample](https://github.com/pankagar/RESTApi-Sample/blob/master/TestStepsSample.cs).

Comment: As I said, your solution referenced a shared step on TFS. I will answer my own question with the solution I used later today.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your update. Always better when you fix it yourself. Please kindly share the solution here, someone will benefit from this if they get stuck with similar scenarios.